# Responsive two column css grid

Tags: html, css, sass

I create 2 columns using css grid as:

```
.Background {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
}
```

But for some reason this is not responsive, I want to change the second column (image column) below first column. How can I achieve this?

Example:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g6f2o793/1/)

Html:

```
<section id="intro" class="SectionGiveAway" />
        <!-- <img src="~@/assets/img/giveAway-header.png" alt="" /> -->
      <section class="Background">
        <div class="SectionGiveAway__container">
          <div class="SectionGiveAway__container-title">sign up</div>
          <div class="SectionGiveAway__container-subtext">
            text
          </div>
          <div class="SectionGiveAway__container-boldtext">
            text
          </div>
          <div class="SectionGiveAway__container-formtext">
            Name:
            <input v-model="name" name="name" autocomplete="name" />
          </div>
          <div class="SectionGiveAway__container-formtext">
            Last name:
            <input 
              v-model="lastName"
              name="lastName"
              autocomplete="lastName"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="SectionGiveAway__container-formtext">
            E-mail:
            <input v-model="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" />
          </div>

          <button
            :disabled="isSubmitting"
            variant="primary"
            type="submit"
            class="SectionGiveAway__container-button"
          >
            SEND
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img
            class="SectionGiveAway__grill-image"
            src="https://picsum.photos/1500"
          />
        </div>
      </section>
```

CSS:

```
.Background {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
}

.SectionGiveAway {
  padding: 5rem 0 4rem;
 
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 4rem 2rem;
  margin-top: 6em;

  display: grid;
  align-items: center;

  &__container {
    padding: 2em;
  }

  &__container-title {
    font-size: 100px;
    color: #a60a2d;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 120px;
  }

  &__container-subtext {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 60px;
  }

  &__container-boldtext {
    font-size: 63px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 75.6px;
  }

  &__container-formtext {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #a60a2d;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  &__container-button {
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }

  &__grill-image {
    height: 60%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow "for some reason this is not responsive"-- I don't see where you've attempted to do any responsive layout aside from using percentages...

Comment: Changing the size of fiddle preview, if the size is smaller than both colums together the second column should go down. I.E if you preview on Iphone X screen, the second column is above first column instead below @AlexanderNied

Comment: What code did you add that makes you think that should happen?

Comment: That's is `SCSS` not `CSS`

Comment: That's the thing, I thought CSS grid did that automatically, but no. What do I need to add for that? @AlexanderNied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Media queries

If you want to resize your grid or stack one of each other when writing css, you should set media queries and write the expected rules in order to the grid behave well.

For example, you have this HTML structure

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
</div>
```

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
```

If you want that to (for example) stack one column on each other when the screen view is less than 992px (md width in bootstrap) you could do a media querie

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  column-gap: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px){
   .grid{
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
   }
}
```

You can set rules when the viewport is smaller and keeping your web looking great. Hope this article helps: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp